# Simulate two centered normal random variables with given variances and given covariance

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

How can I, by the central limit theorem, simulate two random variables $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$ such that $$Z_{1}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})\qquad Z_{2}\sim N\left(0,\dfrac{(\sigma^{2})^{3}}{3}\right)\qquad\mathrm{cov}(Z_{1},Z_{2})=\dfrac{1}{2}(\sigma^{2})^{2}$$ with $\sigma^{2}=4$?
I take two random variable $U$ and $V$ with distribution $N(0,1)$ and generated the random variable $Z_{1}=\sigma U$ and $Z_{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^{3}\left(U+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}V\right)$, but I'm not sure this really works. Thanks, any hint is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For ordinary simulation, a box-muller/polar marsaglia/ziggurat algorithm with cholesky decomposition allows you to simulate a bivariate normal very efficiently. However as you said you want to apply the central limit theorem, which seems that you want to simulate a lot of random variables and show the convergence.

Assume you already have a random number generator which generate $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$. From the given condition, we know that 
$$Corr[Z_1, Z_2] = \frac {1} {2} (\sigma^2)^2 \sqrt{\frac {3} {\sigma^2(\sigma^2)^3 } }
= \frac {\sqrt{3}} {2}$$
So we may try to simulate some easy bivariate distribution satisfying with this correlation requirement, and having mean zero. Let $X_1, X_2$ be a pair of discrete random variables, with
$$ \Pr\{X_i = 1\} = \Pr\{X_i = -1\} = \frac {1} {2}, i = 1, 2$$
Let $\displaystyle \Pr\{X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1\} = p < \frac {1} {2}$. Then
$$ \Pr\{X_1 = 1, X_2 = -1\} = \Pr\{X_1 = -1, X_2 = 1\} = \frac {1} {2} - p$$
$$ \Pr\{X_1 = -1, X_2 = -1\} = 1 - p - (1 - 2p) = p$$
and thus
$$ Var[X_i] = E[X_i^2] = 1, Corr[X_1, X_2] = Cov[X_1, X_2] = E[X_1X_2] = 2p - (1 - 2p) = 4p - 1$$
So by setting $\displaystyle 4p - 1 = \frac {\sqrt{3}} {2} \Rightarrow p = \frac {\sqrt{3} + 2} {8} $, we can satisfy the correlation requirement. Now we have the algorithm.

The rest of the algorithm is left to you.

Edit: Ok it seems that I need to post the full algorithm out:

1. Generate $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$
2. Set 
   $$ (X_{1,i}, X_{2,i}) = \begin{cases} 
   (1, 1) & \text{if} & 0 < U < p \\
   (-1, -1) & \text{if} & p < U < 2p \\
   (1, -1) & \text{if} & \displaystyle 2p < U < \frac {1} {2} + p \\
   (-1, 1) & \text{if} & \displaystyle \frac {1} {2} + p < U < 1 \\
   \end{cases} $$
   where $\displaystyle  p = \frac {\sqrt{3} + 2} {8} $.
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$ times and obtain the following pair
   $$ \frac {1} {\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{1,i}, \frac {1} {\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{2,i} $$
   By multivariate central limit theorem, this vector converges to the bivariate normal distribution
   $$ \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},
   \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac {\sqrt{3}} {2} \\ \frac {\sqrt{3}} {2} & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
4. Finally, we scale this vector by setting 
   $$Z_1 = \sigma\frac {1} {\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{1,i}, 
   Z_2 =  \frac {\sigma} {\sqrt{3}} \frac {1} {\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{2,i}$$
   and this is one way to use simulation to illustrate the CLT.

Comment: Thanks for your naser, but If $\sigma^{2}=4$, what happen? Thanks!

Comment: Completed the example algorithm. The exact value of $\sigma$ does not matter.

Comment: Great answer, and very clear! Thanks. Anyway, my proposed of answer ($Z_{1},Z_{2}$) It works or not so good?

Comment: From your post I think you are just illustrating how to generate a bivariate normal from a pair of independent standard normal through cholesky decomposition. My answer is just showing a way to illustrate the CLT and is not designed for simulation a lot of bivariate normal (since you said from the beginning: "How can I, by the central limit theorem, simulate two random variables"). It really depends on your goal, if you really want to simulate a lot of them then of course you should use efficient algorithm like box-muller etc to obtain a pair of standard normals.